# How to read a single character from an EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, character

I have got an EditText in my Android app where you can type in some text. What I want to do is change every single character to another one (some kind of enciphering). Therefore I first have to read every single character.

How can I do that?

UPDATE:
The text in the edit text is to be encoded on a button click.

Comment: Can't you just read the whole string and do a .ToCharArray()?

Comment: take string from edit-text, and run for loop from index 0 to Length of string, and use charAt(index) method in loop.

Comment: [Check this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify. Do you want to read each character as it is typed, or are you going to encode it all once (like when the user presses a button)?

Comment: @yhyrcanus yeah, good idea. I should have come up with that myself.

Comment: @mtmurdock I want to encode on a button click, see the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InputFilter.

**As you go on typing below snippet will replace each character by $.**

Following Snippet will help you.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            return "$";
         }
        return null;
    }
};

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {filter});
```

**Below is my working snippet**

```
package org.vipul;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AbcActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg);

        InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                 for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    return "$";
                 }

                return null;
            }
        };


        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
            filter
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the whole String, process each character of it, put the results in a String and store it into the target editText or TextView.

If you want to do this live, catch the keyevent of any valid key, retrieve the whole string from edittext, replace the last character by whatever you want, and store the result into the target view.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = edittext.getText().toString();

for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
{
    String singlechar=charAt(i);
    // here you can change char by another chare here

}
```